# Get the Rows separately based on the ID in sql

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table as follows,

```
TypeID   Name         Date
-------------------------------
1        Carrot    1-1-2013
1        Beetroot  1-1-2013
1        Beans     1-1-2013
2        cabbage   1-1-2013
2        potato    1-1-2013
2        tomato    1-1-2013
2        onion     1-1-2013
```

If need 2 rows then it should return 2 rows from TypeId 1 and 2 rows from TypeId 2.If need the only 4 rows, means I have to get 4 rows from TypeId 1 and 4 rows from TypeId 2
but TypeId 1 has only 3  rows so we need to get only 3 rows for typeId 1

How to do that? Shall I add RowNumber?

Comment: what if you need 4 rows

Comment: Always 3 per TypeID, or just "all you can grab from lowest to highest type"?

Comment: Do you always get all rows from `TypeId 1`? For instance, if need only 3 rows, do you get all three rows from `TypeId 1` and none from `TypeId 2`?

Comment: "I need 4 of each, if they exist; otherwise, give me as many of that type as you can".  Is that a correct summary?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server;

EDIT: Your question changed slightly;

If you want want a maximum of x items per category, you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx);

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TypeID ORDER BY Name) rn FROM Table1
)
SELECT TypeID, Name, [Date] FROM cte 
WHERE rn <=3       -- here is where your x goes
ORDER BY TypeID;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6563f/14).

Comment: Why do you need the "TOP 8" in the second query?

Comment: I don't think specifying `TOP N` in the second query is necessary to meet the OP's requirement (by my understanding of it).

Comment: @Greg You're correct, I did not see the edit of the question. Updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query to order by the `TypeID`.

Then, if you're using SQL, you could use [`SELECT TOP N`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) or `LIMIT N` (depending on the DB), or with TSQL and SQL Server, use [`TOP(N)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to take the top N rows.

If you're using a LINQ based ORM from your C# code, then you can use [`Take(N)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx), which automatically creates the appropriate query based on the provider details to limit the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a query to select your 3 rows from type 1.....and then the however many rows from type 2 and then add the results together.

Comment: This is fairly inefficient, since it'd be multiple round trips to the DB. Better to do it in a single query in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE(TypeID,Name,Date,RowNo)
AS
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)  from TableVEG
)
Select Top(@noofRows*2) * from CTE where RowNo<=@noofRows order by rowno
```

The above query worked.. Thank u all... :-)